# error al ejecutar ng serve -o usando vite como constructor de la aplicación

Tags: angular, vite

estoy usando **node: 20.11.1**, **npm: 10.5**, **@angular/cli: 17.3**, al crear un nuevo proyecto usando:
`ng new <project-name> --standalone false`

y al correr le server con: `ng serve -o`, lanza el siguiente error en consola:

```
<myApp_path>\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1084
        return callback(new Error(error), null);                        ^
    Error: The service was stopped
    at
<myApp_path>\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1084:25
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (<myApp_path>\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:704:9)
    at Socket.afterClose (<myApp_path>\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:694:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Node.js v20.11.1
```

al parecer el problema es con **Vite** y **esbuild**